# How do I count the number of posts a certain category has?

Tags: sql

I have a table of categories (tags) in `list_tags`:

```
tag_id  tag_name
  1 social
  2 gaming
  3 design
  4 code
  5 facebook
```

Then I have blog posts in `blogs`:

```
blog_id blog_title
1       post1
2       post2
3       post3
```

And at last I have a table `join_blog_tags` which defines what categories (tags) each blog post belongs to:

```
blog_tag_id blog_tag_post_id    blog_tag_list_id
1           1                     1
2           1                     2
3           2                     2
4           2                     4
```

I need to somehow join those 3 tables and produce the total number of blog posts in each tag.

Like this:

social | 12
gaming | 14
facebook | 30
etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a [join](http://beginner-sql-tutorial.com/sql-joins.htm) in conjunction with [`GROUP BY`](http://beginner-sql-tutorial.com/sql-group-by-clause.htm):

```
SELECT tag_name, COUNT(tag_name)
FROM list_tags lt
 INNER JOIN join_blog_tags bt
    ON lt.tag_id = bt.blog_tag_list_id
GROUP BY tag_name
```

For a count of posts per list you don't need to join on the `blogs` table, as the information already exists in the join table.